# How to click a button of tag type <input> in selenium | Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to submit a form. The problem is when trying to click the submit button, nothing happens. I think the problem is that this button has a tag of `<input>`:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">
```

I think it is clicking on an input that won't trigger the function, so is there a way to trigger the function. I tried to use javascript code like:

```
self.dataBrowser.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('//input[@type='submit']').click()")
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: You only want one element so use `querySelector` instead: `"document.querySelector('input[@type='submit']').click()"`.

Comment: it throughs this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list` @caTS

Comment: Right... I forgot to escape the quotes inside the string: `"document.querySelector('input[@type=\\'submit\\']').click()"`.

Comment: now it gives this :
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[@type='submit']' is not a valid selector.`
@caTS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').click()
```

make sure `input[type='submit']` is unique locator for that element on the page

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[@type="submit"]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: I see, my fault. Mixed XPath and CSS Selectors syntax. Please try the updated version

Comment: no error, but it doesn't click though

Comment: Well, this is another issue. We need to debug it. Please share all your selenium code including the link to we can debug. But the original problem is resolved now

Comment: do you ensure that clicking a button but with tag input will trigger it or not ?

Comment: I can not ensure nothing. We need to see your code and the page you working on to see what happens there and what can be improved.

Comment: I Can't share the link, is there another way

Comment: not sure, we need to see why it is not working. But again, your original question here is resolved

Comment: but my question is to click a button with tag <input>

Comment: OK, if so this question can't be resolved since you can't provide minimal debugging details.